# Kids’ picture book involving a friendly robot taking kids around the galaxy

Tags: story-identification, robots, childrens-novel, space-exploration

I recall reading a book frequently in the late-80s or early-90s, but cannot remember the name and would love to find the book for my son.

In the book, a group of kids are taken around the galaxy by a friendly robot/rocket. I distinctly remember learning that the Horsehead Nebula exists because of a picture in the book.

Any help would be much appreciated.